# How to translate the new Gmail API message/thread IDs to X-GM-MSGID/X-GM-THRID and

Tags: gmail-api

I'm trying to use the Message get api and it works but I'm unable to use the gmail message id (X-GM-MSGID) or message id when trying to retrieve.  Does anybody know if there is a way to translate the new gmail api id's with either the message id or X-GM-MSGID?

Answer (score 4):

The Gmail API uses the same message Ids as the web UI (you'll see them in the URL bar when you've loaded the message).  The IMAP X-GM-MSGID is the same value but in decimal format rather than hex string format.

"The message ID is a 64-bit unsigned integer and is the decimal equivalent for the ID hex string used in the web interface and the Gmail API."

According to:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_the_gmail_unique_message_id_x-gm-msgid

Comment: That should work, I've used the technique in the past to get a web URL for an IMAP message.